# Empty datat to jqgrid to diaplay No Data in the Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Am having a JQGrid and am loading the data with the Ajax call to the MVC Controller. and in controller it is a DataTable which am converting to a Class and runtime and returning the JSON.

```
if (data.Rows.Count > 0)
 {
 List<Classs> item = new List<Classs>();
 var result = new
 {
 total = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)count / grid.PageSize),
  page = grid.PageIndex,
 records = count,
  rows = (from i in data.AsEnumerable()
  select new Classs
  {
                       xx= i.Field<string>("x"),
                       yy= i.Field<string>("y"),

    }).ToArray()
        };
 return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

  }
```

and in else part how do i return the data if the table is empty so that grid shows "No Records Found" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass out a JSON result even if the results are empty.  You could pass out a bool if the data to be displayed is 0 via a `userdata` parameter or you could test on the client side if there are no results to be displayed (which can also be triggered via filtering though) with something like:

```
  loadComplete: function () {
        if ($(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount') == 0) {
           //display message if empty jqGrid, etc        
        }
```

Comment: am getting undefined for $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'reccount')

Comment: Is it inside your loadComplete?

Comment: Paste up the section, I'm not sure why it would be failing as I took this directly from production code in my own project.